# Show a little mapview inside a infowindow when click marker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maps, google-maps-markers

I was wondering if there's any way to do something like this...!

[image]

When click the marker show this info window where i can show a little more closer mapview of that area...

Comment: did you try anything...?

Comment: Hello there! Yes. Actually thats a View that contains a fragmentMap and thats what happend for now if i click a marker.

Comment: The InfoWindow is shown using a Bitmap drawn on a Canvas.  So, there is no way to put interactive elements in an InfoWindow.